# what's the syntax to represent a printer in fqdn style?

Tags: windows, network-printer

I am trying to send a print command to a printer via telnet.

Normally I would send it to telnet://printer125:9100

but I am not able to access the printer directly. server admin indicated that I need to go though the print server.  \server1.domain.com\printer125

what is the correct syntax to reach printer printer125 on server1.domain.com

is it something like this?

> telnet://server1.domain.com:9100/printer125

Comment: does your admin know that you are trying to use telnet to print? looks like they gave you a windows file and print sharing path, not somthing you can use via telnet.

Comment: Im no expert  but I dont think you can "get where you are going" with a simple telnet command if you need to use Windows file sharing protocol. You may need to install samba and print via that.  I am sure that if the admins advice is correct (ie access to the printer is only through smb as implied) tcp port 445, not 9100 needs to be involved - but I expect there is a lot more to the protocol then just dumping the file on port 445.

Comment: You need to install a local driver and map a port to that network printer.  If you are trying to print something, the windows GDI needs to translate it into whatever printer language needed before sending the file.  What do you mean by "trying to send a print command"? You mean print a file or change a default print font or duplex setting?  The latter is embedded in your print job.  Perhaps I am not understanding.  I have written over an hundred print drivers and there isn't enough information here to help you.

Comment: Yes. i found docs that indicates we should be able to use smb://. Waiting on local resource to confirm it printed out.